# Files to be required for generating apk file in React native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I've started to learn react native and I've tried some sample app.The app is installed in emulator and working properly,and I would to share this app with my friends so I've created apk file using [generating signed apk](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

In that reference link they told that,

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

this command (assembleRelease) will bundle all the javascript.Are javascript files alone enough to create apk file?We are running this command inside android folder,wont it take java files?Can anyone please explain in detail what will happen and what are the files bundled after giving the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this URL will help.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)

Look at Architecture part too.

Answer (score 0):

Once keystore file is generated and linked in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties and android/app/build.gradle`, running `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` from root folder (or `./gradlew assembleRelease` from android folder) will bundle the app with all necessary files and generate the apk.
You will find the signed apk (app-release.apk) in `android/app/build/outputs/apk` folder

Hope this helps